# SQL - How to exclude multiple consonants or chain of consonants

Tags: sql

My immense gratitude for helping this novice.

I am trying to compose a query that would exclude words that contain 4 consecutive consonants or more.

I have a very simple database in OpenOffice Base. I have 1 field (column) in the table with one word in each field (column). I have about 100,000 words I need to sort through. I just don't know how to create the proper syntax (statement) to do this.

I begin with

```
SELECT column_name

FROM table_name

WHERE column-name
```

???????

Thanks immensely for any help.

Comment: There are plenty of basic SQL tutorials online.

Comment: I'd add another column and mark them up in a one off job. Going to  be painfully slow.

Comment: There might be lot's of basic tutorials out there, but this is not a basic question.

Comment: I did go through the W3Schools tutorials and some others and couldn't find an example like this. I also scoured the forums here and elsewhere with no luck before I posted this question. I was able to widdle my list down from 100,000 words to about 10,000 words using query parameters I learned, but I'm still trying to get the list better. Thanks for the feedback and I'm still open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming consonants are anything but "a", "e", "i", "o", and "u", then you want to find all words where these do not appear in four consecutive characters.  Here is one way to write such an expression:

```
where word not like '%[^aeiou][^aeiou][^aeiou][^aeiou]%'
```

Different SQL dialects sometimes have different formats for `like` patterns, so this pattern may not work everywhere.  The idea, however, can be expressed in any SQL dialect.

EDIT:

Perhaps Open Office uses Access wildcards instead:

```
where word not like '*[!aeiou][!aeiou][!aeiou][!aeiou]*'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear response. Your expression makes perfect sense. Unfortunately it didn't work for me and I think my problem may be related to using OpenOffice Base as I was unable to get any SQL [charlist] Wildcard expressions to work. I'm not sure that OpenOffice plays nice with standard or native SQL, and I couldn't get it to work running their option called "run SQL command directly". Again I'm a rookie at this so I may be making some bone-headed mistake. Anyway, thanks again, and I'll keep trying to figure this out.